# Running IdentityServer3 behind an NGINX forward Proxy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nginx, identityserver3

I am attempting to forward proxy and .NET MVC application co-hosting IdentityServer3 behind NGINX. As a proof of concept, I am running NGINX in a VirtualBox VM on my notebook. The login process seems to work properly until after I've authenticated the user and I'm redirecting back into the application. After turning on all the logging for IdentityServer3 I can see that there are no errors being returned, tokens I expect to be created are created and so forth. But I also notice that when the response message to the logon to not set the .AspNet.Cookies cookie. I believe that is the problem.

I suspect this is some sort of foolish setup issue in my environment. I have defined the virtual machine's IP address as goober.mydomain.com in my Windows hosts file.  My NGINX config file follows. Does anyone notice something obvious that I am doing wrong?

```
    user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    server {

            large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

            location /phoenix {
                    rewrite ^/phoenix(.*) /$1 break;

                    proxy_pass http://USSTP90000005/;
            }

            location /api/i19n {
                    proxy_pass http://USSTP90000005:83/;
            }

            location /api/login {
                    proxy_pass http://USSTP90000005:84/api/login;
            }

            location /api/users {
                    proxy_pass http://USSTP90000005:84/;
            }

            location /id {

                    rewrite ^/id(.*) /$1 break;

                    proxy_pass http://USSTP90000005:84/;

                    proxy_cookie_path   /identity /;
            }

            location /identity {
                    proxy_pass http://USSTP90000005:84/identity/;
            }

            location /templates {
                    proxy_pass http://USSTP90000005:84/templates/;
            }

            location /bundles {
                    proxy_pass http://USSTP90000005:84/bundles/;
            }

}

#include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
#default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
              '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
              '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with NGinx, but you appear to not be doing ssl between it & the sites. This could be the cause of your troubles, since Identity Server & the client expect to use SSL. You might need to disable ssl requirements, but then have NGinx do the SSL between it & the browser.